# R, DMwR-package, knnImputation function is not found

Tags: r, knn

I am facing a issue while doing knnImputaion in R. Even I have installed DMwR package, but upon executing the knnImputation function, error occurs saying: could not find function "knnImputation"

Please help.

```
install.packages("DMwR")
df = knnImputation(df, k=5)
sum(is.na(df))
```

Console says,

```
Error in knnImputation(df, k=5) :
could not find function "knnImputation"
```

Comment: After you install the library with `install.packages("DMwR")` you must also load it with `library(DMwR)`

Comment: Oh!! my silly mistake. Thank you so much @G5W